# ios - update UI inside block

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, asynchronous, uilabel

I make a call to the youtube API to get the title of a video. I then want to display the title of the video on the screen in a table. How do I access the `title` after the block has finished executing?

Here's the code to get the title

```
-(void)getVideoTitle:(NSString *)urlStr success:(void (^)(NSDictionary *responseDict))success{

urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails%%2C+snippet%%2C+statistics&id=%@&key={API_KEY}",urlStr];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];
// Create your request
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Send the request asynchronously
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *connectionError) {

    // Callback, parse the data and check for errors
    if (data && !connectionError) {
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

        if (!jsonError) {
            success(jsonResult);
           // NSLog(@"Response from YouTube: %@", jsonResult);
        }
    }
}] resume];
```

}

Here's how I call the above function:

```
    [self getVideoTitle:@"zB4I68XVPzQ" success:^(NSDictionary *responseDict){
    NSArray *itemsArray = [responseDict valueForKey:@"items"];
    NSDictionary *item = itemsArray[0];
    NSDictionary* snippet = [item valueForKey:@"snippet"];
    NSString *title = [snippet valueForKey:@"title"];
}];
```

How do I get access the `title` variable outside the block after the block has finished executing?

I have tried the following with no luck

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self updateMyUserInterfaceOrSomething];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
    NSString* recievedTitle __block = nil; //title is here, after block below run

    [self getVideoTitle:@"zB4I68XVPzQ" success:^(NSDictionary *responseDict){
        NSArray *itemsArray = [responseDict valueForKey:@"items"];
        NSDictionary *item = itemsArray[0];
        NSDictionary* snippet = [item valueForKey:@"snippet"];
        recievedTitle = [snippet valueForKey:@"title"]; //here you write it
        // or
        NSString *title = [snippet valueForKey:@"title"];
        [self updateInterfaceWithTitle: title]
    }];

///

- (void)updateInterfaceWithTitle:(NSString*)title{
   //use title here
}
```